# Implementing a Convolution Neural Network from Scratch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a simple question. I am trying to implement a CNN in pure python to understand how the magic happens.

I have input a set of RGB images, `32 x 32` in size.

I made a convolutional filter that converts this `1 x 3 x 32 x 32` vector

to `1 x 1 x 32 x 32` and then I apply a maxpool layer which makes the size `1 x 1 x 16 x 16`.

My question is how do I classify by applying a softmax now?

How can I pass gradients if I apply softmax on the 16 x 16 dimensional vector?

Comment: I would recommend flattening the `16x16` feature to a `256`-dimensional feature vector, then applying a dense layer with a softmax activation. This is how it is usually done, although `GlobalMaxPooling` and `GlobalAveragePooling` are other ways of "flattening" the features.

Comment: @LukeDeLuccia yes, but then how to pass gradients back?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13587/back-propagation-through-max-pooling-layers